# Acess static nested object in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am able to set 'requestType' as ComponentA.getApiParameters.requestType = 'SomeValue', but while setting the nested object params, ComponentA.getApiParameters.params.parameterType = 'SomeValue'. It's throwing run time error as

'Can not set property 'parameterType' of undefined,

```
      static sApiParameters = {
        params:{
          parameterType: '',
          key:'',
          value:''
        },
        requestType: 'GET',
      };

      static getApiParameters() {
        return HomeScreen.sApiParameters;
      }


onButtonClick = () =>{
      ComponentA.getApiParameters.requestType = this.state.keyType;
      ComponentA.getApiParameters.params.key = this.state.key;
      this.props.navigation.goBack();
    }
```

Comment: I just tried your example and It's worked. Can you share also where do you put these lines in your code?

Comment: onButtonClick = () =>{
      ComponentA.getApiParameters.requestType = this.state.keyType;
     ComponentA.getApiParameters.params.key = this.state.key;
      this.props.navigation.goBack();
    }